# How to convert dynamic columns into rows in Oracle 11g?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to convert dynamic columns into row in Oracle 11g. I know it can possible using unpivot, but only pre-exists columns not with dynamic columns.

Data Input:

```
select 'Bulding1', 'Building2', 'Building3', 'Building4', 'Building5','Building6' 
from dual;
```

Expected output:

```
Column_Name
-----------
- Building1
- Building2
- Building3
- Building4
- Building5
- Building6
- Building7
```

Comment: How do you build a query with a variable number of columns? Are you using dynamic SQL?

Comment: not dynamic sql fully, normal sql. i have two query, first one returning this dynamic data to outer query and now this outer query need to make this dynamic data into rows.

Comment: It's not that clear to me; how can the innermost query give a variable number of columns?

Answer (score 1):

Use `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT 'Building1' AS column_name FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Building2' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Building3' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Building4' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Building5' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Building6' FROM DUAL;
```

or use `UNPIVOT`:

```
SELECT column_name
FROM   (
  SELECT 'Building1',
         'Building2',
         'Building3',
         'Building4',
         'Building5',
         'Building6' 
  FROM   DUAL
)
UNPIVOT(
  column_name FOR name IN (
    "'BUILDING1'",
    "'BUILDING2'",
    "'BUILDING3'",
    "'BUILDING4'",
    "'BUILDING5'",
    "'BUILDING6'"
  )
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help MT0, The first one is working fine but the second one giving an error of ORA-00904: : invalid identifier.

Comment: @Palan The second one works for me on Oracle 12c and on [DB<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f31f286bf3b08588e3c2715fd005c540)

Comment: MT0 i am also using 12c but still getting the invalid identifier error. This the actual version of DB : Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: MT0 If it possible then can you please post the screenshot of success of second query.